# Sitecore performance counters - Media.cachehits

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm trying to debug a performance issue with a Sitecore 6.6 site and installed the Sitecore Counters on my CD node.

I'm seeing lots of hits/misses for the various data caches, but the Media.CacheHits and Media.CacheMisses both read 0... is this either a problem (or is this a bad counter)?

I can see that MediaCaching is enabled; I get lots of files in the cache directory on the CD node which get cleaned up properly every evening - but this counter reading 0 has me worried.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know enough about the performance counters, but it might be that the hits and misses are 0 because it's getting its 'cached' media files from disk instead of memory. Also turning on performance counters allegedly make a drain in performance, so only use them temporarily.

When it comes to your performance problems, do they seem to be related to media items or was this just a question about the counters being 0?

In any case, to debug the performance you could also try the debugger and check the [Sitecore guide on performance tuning](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/CMS%20Performance%20Tuning%20Guide.aspx).